# Python argparse behavior differs depending on launch mode (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, argparse

This is a excerpt of my **test-argparse.py** piece of software:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import sys

def manage_command_line():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple Description')
    parser.add_argument('code', type=str, help='Project code')
    return parser.parse_args()

args = manage_command_line()
print(args)
print(sys.version)
```

When called as a parameter of the interpreter (result is correct and expected):

```
c:\Python27\python.exe test-argparse.py KB130
Namespace(code='KB130')
2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

However if call it directly, relying in windows file association, the result is completely different:

```
C:\Users\PGO\Documents\docauto>test-argparse.py KB130
usage: test-argparse.py [-h] code
test-argparse.py: error: too few arguments
```

The definition of Windows file group association and the redirection is standard and as described in Python 2.7.14 manual (chapter 3.3.4):

```
C:\Users\PGO\Documents\docauto>assoc .py
.py=Python.File

C:\Users\PGO\Documents\docauto>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*

C:\Users\PGO\Documents\docauto>
```

And consistent with my system paths, although my Python version is 2.7.12 and not 2.7.14, which probably makes no difference at all.

Question: Is there a way for obtaning a consistent result in both cases? I would like a consistent behavior of the application independent of the way it is executed.

Comment: Wish I could be of more help, but it performs as expected for both Python 3.6.4 and Python 2.7.14 on Windows 10.

Comment: The 2.7.12/2.7.14 difference will not matter, to remove that from consideration.

Comment: Python 2's documentation is wrong.  `assoc` and `ftype` have nothing to do with the current file association for the current user. They only show you the system .py association and Python.File program identifier that are defined in "HKLM\Software\Classes". The per-user "HKCU\Software\Classes" definitions have priority and may be different, plus Explorer caches and stores associations and the user's locked choice under "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts".

Comment: @eryksun your proposal is accurate, and that situation was apparently creating the problem in my machine, as HKCU\Software\Classes is pointing to a different (Python 3) instance. I still have to test it correctly but this gives an answer to the effects I am experiencing. I cannot however raise your reputation as you commented instead of answered.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get:

`C:\Users>ftype Python.File`

> Python.File="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*

Both cases work for me correctly. I have Python 3.6, that could explain the difference in executable name.

Comment: I have the same experience as well. Seems OP's Python file association is misconfigured.